# Linq to CRM (early bound) join statement throws exception when lambda expression doesn't

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a bug in the Microsoft linq to CRM provider, or am I doing something that linqToCrm doesn't support?

I have a simple function that determines if the user is assigned a role which doesn't work.

```
public static bool IsSystemUserInRole(Guid systemUserId,
                                      string roleName,
                                      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService service)
{
    using (var crmService = new CrmContext(service))
    {
        return (from sr in crmService.SystemUserRolesSet
                join r in crmService.RoleSet
                    on sr.RoleId.Value equals r.RoleId.Value
                where sr.SystemUserId.Value == systemUserId && r.Name == roleName
                select sr.SystemUserId).FirstOrDefault() != null;
    }
}
```

But strangely enough, if I rewrite it as two lambda expressions, it works fine.

```
public static bool IsSystemUserInRole(Guid systemUserId,
                                      string roleName,
                                      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService service)
{
    using (var crmService = new CrmContext(service))
    {
        var role = crmService.RoleSet.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);
        return role != null 
                && crmService.SystemUserRolesSet.FirstOrDefault(
                    ur => ur.SystemUserId == systemUserId
                          && ur.RoleId == role.RoleId) != null;
    }
}
```

The Exception is

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: 'SystemUserRoles' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'name'. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).

and the stack trace is

> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.RetrieveEntityCollection(OrganizationRequest request, NavigationSource source)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute(QueryExpression qe, Boolean throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection projection, NavigationSource source, List`1 linkLookups, String& pagingCookie, Boolean& moreRecords)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](QueryExpression qe, Boolean throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection projection, NavigationSource source, List`1 linkLookups)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)
>      at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>      at CRM.Business.IntegrationServices.SystemUserService.IsSystemUserInRole(Guid systemUserId, String roleName, IOrganizationService service)
>      at CRM.Plugin.OnExecute(IServiceProvider provider)

Comment: Would you believe I wrote a LINQ query today where I tried including two entities in the `where` statement and only figured out what to do by googling the error and finding this question? Amazing.

Comment: @PeterMajeed That's the beauty of StackOverflow...  Everyone helping everyone.

Comment: And the *horror* of certain Microsoft design decisions... :-)

Comment: vote (to tell microsoft) to correct this ->  https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/733303/linq-query-where-clause-for-composite-conditions-against-multiple-entities

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Where` statements from different entities need to be introduced in [separate where statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx).

> The where clause applies a filter to the results, often using a
>   Boolean expression. The filter specifies which elements to exclude
>   from the source sequence. Each where clause can only contain
>   conditions against a single entity type. A composite condition
>   involving multiple entities is not valid. Instead, each entity should
>   be filtered in separate where clauses.

The below should probably take care of it.

```cs
public static bool IsSystemUserInRole(Guid systemUserId,
                                      string roleName,
                                      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService service)
{
    using (var crmService = new CrmContext(service))
    {
        return (from sr in crmService.SystemUserRolesSet
                join r in crmService.RoleSet
                    on sr.RoleId.Value equals r.RoleId.Value
                where sr.SystemUserId.Value == systemUserId
                where r.Name == roleName
                select sr.SystemUserId).FirstOrDefault() != null;
    }
}
```